# Share a session between 2 flask apps running on different servers

Tags: python, flask

I am using client side sessions. The requirement is to redirect from 1 flask server which already have a user session data to another flask app on a different server and use the same client session information to make sure the user has already logged in if not send them back to the 1st server for authentication.

If ***possible*** i would like to keep using the client side sessions. If not any information regarding the alternative will be helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Normally there is 2 options.
First, client side authentication using token like JWT (Json Web Token), this approach authenticate every request using token included in header and no need additional server.
Second, server side approach with additional session store like Redis for multiple backends.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have followed through with a server side redis sessions. Now, the flask applications each have their own domains. How should i proceed with the integration. Its almost like SSO login in 2 different applications that im trying to achieve.